how to line break on dataraptor formula
How can I break a line in a formula in a dataraptor, or format the text, I need the formatted text to display in a document template.
CONCAT("TEXT1: ",%Acc:FirstName%, "lineBreak Here!!!"  "TEXT2 ",%Acc:LastName%)


I had a project where we had the same issue. It turned out that the newline character is being interpreted differently by various text editors like Microsoft Word/ Google Docs/ LibreOffice etc.
Play around with inserting \r (LF - Newline) and \n (CR - Carriage Return) characters in places where you would like to have a line break.
Be aware that the solution won't fix your problem if you plan to generate PDF files out of your template (due to the document generation mechanism Omnistudio utilizes and the EOL encoding). But if you plan to generate Word documents only, then CONCAT("TEXT1: ",%Acc:FirstName%, "\r\n"  "TEXT2 ",%Acc:LastName%) combination should work depending on the text editor that you use.
I'm sorry that I don't have any direct answer to your question, but I hope it will give you some idea, and will allow you to dive deeper into this problem

Assuming your data raptor returns a response on Omniscript. You can add a <br> tag where you want the line break. From data raptor it will return a string including <br>, but when this gets displayed on omniscript UI. It would add a line break.
DR:

Omniscript Preview:


This partially worked, I need to break the line of text that will be passed as a parameter to the document template token, in this case this unfortunately doesn't work...

Please explain ur use case with example if possible.
